# Problema al mostrar el contenido de un array en un fichero

Tags: java, netbeans

El problema que tengo es que necesito guardar las temperaturas de una semana en un fichero y cuando lo hago, en el fichero solo me muestra la ultima temperatura introducida.

No se donde esta el error para que me muestre todas la temperaturas.

```
public class Principal {

public static void introducirTempe() throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double dias[];
    //int aux = 0;
    String diasSemana[] = {"Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado", "Domingo"};
    dias = new double[7];
    for (int x = 0; x < diasSemana.length; x++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce la temperatura del " + diasSemana[x]);
        dias[0] = sc.nextDouble();

        FileWriter f = null;
        PrintWriter p = null;
        try {
            f = new FileWriter("Temperaturas.txt");
            p = new PrintWriter(f);

            for (int j = 0; j < dias.length; j++) {
                p.println(dias[j]);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }finally {
            f.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

También dejo el main

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcion = -1;
    while (opcion != 0) {

        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("Selecciona una de las opciones ");
        System.out.println("1. Introducir temperatura del dia");
        System.out.println("2. Realizar estadistica");
        System.out.println("3. Salir");
        opcion = sc.nextInt();
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                introducirTempe();
                break;
            case 2:
                //estadistica();
                break;
            case 3:
                //salir();
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás escribiendo todo el tiempo en la misma posición del `array` (en la posición 0):

```
dias[0] = sc.nextDouble();
```

Si tu idea es introducir la temperatura por cada día de la semana, deberías aprovechar tu variable `x` del bucle `for` para ir introduciendo temperaturas en el `array`:

```
dias[x] = sc.nextDouble();
```